# JPA / HIBERNATE Entity from two inherited classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can some one help me with example / idea how to deal with this scenario.
I have class Animal and class Cat , that extend Animal.
In Animal I have some field, also some new field in my Cat class.
So I have to create hibernate entity, that store my Cat in db and somehow to have info about parents field.

Comment: Start here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use annotation @Inherance

with

`strategy=InheritanceType.ONLY_ONE_TABLE (or SINGLE_TABLE)
strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS
strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED`

Comment: why not use TABLE_PER_SUBCLASS ? is it more suitrable ?

Comment: it's up to you according to your needs